# The difference between sizeof and .size() for a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, mpi

I'm implementing a MPI code and I'm using `MPI_Bcast` function. One of the function's components is the number of data sent which is here the size of a vector called `l_nMinplacesPos`. I want to share the size of this vector. I tried once `sizeof l_nMinplacesPos` which returned 32 and when I used `l_nMinplacesPos.size()` I got 2 as a size of the vector!!!. I'm confused which one of them displays the actual size of the vector? and what is the difference between both of them?

```
void ParaStochSimulator::broad_casting(long j){
std::cout << "i'm broad_casting" << std::endl;
l_nMinplacesPos = (*m_pcTransitionsInfo)[j]->GetManipulatedPlaces();
double val;
l_anMarking.reserve(l_nMinplacesPos.size());
for (auto lnpos : l_nMinplacesPos)
{
    val = m_anCurrentMarking[lnpos];
    l_anMarking.push_back(val);
}
for (auto marking : l_anMarking)
{
    std::cout << marking << std::endl;
}
MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, sizeof l_nMinplacesPos, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD); //->here i used  l_nMinplacesPos.size() instead.
```

}

```
void ParaStochSimulator::SimulateSingleRun()
{
//prepare a run
PrepareRun();
while ((m_nCurrentTime < m_nOutputEndPoint) && IsSimulationRunning())
    {
    deterMinTau();
    if (mnprocess_id == 0)
    {
        SimulateSingleStep1();
        std::cout << "current time:*****" << m_nCurrentTime << std::endl;
        broad_casting(m_nMinTransPos);
        std::cout << "size of mani place :" << sizeof l_nMinplacesPos << std::endl;

    }
}
PostProcessRun();
MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, sizeof l_nMinplacesPos, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //->here i used l_nMinplacesPos.size() instead.
std::cout << "size of mani place :" << sizeof l_nMinplacesPos << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Do you want to know how many entries are in the vector?  Then you use `vector::size()`.  There is no way `sizeof()` could help you there, since it is a *compile-time* constant.  It has no idea how many items at runtime you're putting into the vector.

Comment: Also `sizeof` returns the number of bytes a type `T` takes up.  That's why it only knows compile-time information.  You could have done a small test and found out that `sizeof(your_vector)` stays the same whether you have no items, or 10,000 items in your vector.

Comment: MPI just copies the memory like memcpy. Since vector is not trivially copiable, this is undefined behaviour regardless of the size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.size()` returns the number of elements in the vector. That's what you should be using.

`sizeof` gives you the number of *bytes* used by the object definition, excluding any additional storage it has allocated through the use of pointers. It is a static constant generated by the compiler at compile time, based on the declaration of the `vector` class.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning about `sizeof()` is also the fact, that when you work directly on your array's cells' content (especially strings), it may cut off the length of that specific cell to 8 bytes. On my practical exam I had a task to create a C/C++ program, which locates the first letter of every word inserted into the array. After using `sizeof()` it returned only first 8 characters of that array, the rest has been thrown out of memory, so be careful.